# Alternative to get "config variables" as static values

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I was looking for some global values as static, for like, if some value is nil|null put this default value, example like put default url in link in eex if there isn't declare in assigns.

Example:

```
# Create a link with default return if URL not found
 <%= 
     link "Go back",
         to: assigns[:url_back] || Application.get_env(:app_name, :default_values)[:url_back]
 %>

# example of in ./config/config.exs
config :app_name, :default_values,
    url_back: "/index"
```

- My question is there is an alternative to this?
- Can I use a module
  for this? like:

```
defmodule StaticValues do
   def url_back(), do: "/index"
end
# note: I do not know how to import or use in eex...
```

Comment: The `eex` template is directly linked to its view module, everything you import there will be available inside of the template.

Comment: If you want, you might post your own answer, but please avoid ruining answers provided by others. Thank you.

Comment: sorry @Aleksei Matiushkin, that was not my intention, I just want to add some information to the answer for other people like me, that are new in elixir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to go the module route, you can just call the function in your EEx template:

```rb
 <%= 
     link "Go back",
         to: assigns[:url_back] || StaticValues.url_back()
 %>
```

Or you could even make a helper function for defaulting to the static value:

```rb
# You would probably want to rename this module in this case
defmodule StaticValues do
  def get_with_fallback(assigns, key) do
    Map.get(assigns, key, apply(__MODULE__, key, []))
  end

  def url_back, do: "/index"
end
```

To be used like

```rb
 <%= 
     link "Go back",
         to: StaticValues.get_with_fallback(assigns, :url_back)
 %>
```

If there's an assign, it's used:

```rb
iex> StaticValues.get_with_fallback(%{url_back: "/home"}, :url_back)
"/home"
```

If there's not, the fallback is used:

```rb
iex> StaticValues.get_with_fallback(%{}, :url_back)
"/index"
```

Comment: @DarckBlezzer per your edit, when would you prefer `StaticValues.get_with_fallback(:url_back)` over `StaticValues.url_back()`?

Comment: I think it would depend of the context and the best option for better use, in this case you have both. with this example I get an idea of what to do, thanks for this answer and your time to performance the answer..

Comment: With the second edit, I don't see the need for a manual fallback when the point of the function is to do the falling back for you. And `or` only works on boolean values.

Answer (score 2):

While Brett’s answer is perfectly correct, there might be another approach, if you want to be more DRY.

Simply weakly [`Map.merge/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Map.html?#merge/2) the defaults before rendering the template.

```rb
assigns =
  :app_name
  |> Application.get_env(:default_values)
  |> Map.new()
  |> Map.merge(assigns)
```

Comment: I like your approach way better. What's the advantage of a `Map.merge/3` with that conflict resolution function vs. just `Map.merge(defaults, assigns)`? I would think they would yield the same thing.

Comment: @BrettBeatty indeed, thanks. I would still undelete your answer; more approaches are better than one.